# Testing alert in HtmlUnit

Tags: javascript, .net, singleton, alert, htmlunit

I understand the example a little from the example "Watching for 'alerts'" on this page: [HtmlUnit- Javascript Tutorial](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/javascript-howto.html).  As a beginner in .NET, I do not understand how the Collections.singletonList works and I browse through the www that it is a function in Java.  I am trying integrate this with validation where an alert box pops up when the user input is invalid.  As a start I did write this first:

`Dim alert As AlertHandler`
`webCLient.setAlertHandler(alert)`
`webCLient.getAlertHandler().handleAlert(page, "")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that to use the singletonList, I had to completely put java.util.Collections.singletonList for it to work in .NET